# Por que o CSS tem tantas unidades de medidas?

Tags: css, css3

Após aparecer a janelinha de auto-complete, me deparei com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e logo me questionei: **por que o CSS tem tantas unidades de medidas diferentes?**

Comment: Dá para por código em vez da imagem?

Comment: @JorgeB. a imagem não tem nenhum código, é apenas uma referência para onde surgiu a minha dúvida.

Comment: Seja como for, acho que ficava melhor com código/texto.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

É porque não temos só uma "mídia de exibição", vc pode ter que configurar uma página web para saída de impressão, como qualquer projeto tipográfico para vc ter mais controle do como um `PX` de tela vai aparecer no papel vc pode fazer um `@media print {}` e usar unidades de medida para impressão. A vantagem disso é garantir que tanto na tela quanto na impressão vc vai entregar uma boa experiencia de leitura para o usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vários softwares de "impressão" como o Corel por exemplo, trabalham com medidas em Pontos ou Centimentros/Milímitros, etc. Esse é só um exemplo para impressão. Ainda existem formas de vc configurar a página de impressão usando o `@page,` e nessa `at rule` vc pode definir o tamanho da página, se é `A4` ou `A5` por exemplo, e ainda definir as margens em `CM` ou `MM` por exemplo

```
@page {
  size: A4;
}
@page :left {
  margin-right: 200pt;
}

@page :right {
  margin-left: 2cm;
}
```

---

O exemplo acima foi basicamente para impressão, mas imagina que vc vai ter em um algum comércio algo tipo um *tablet* que o usuário apenas pode interagir com a tela, e essa tela não tem *scroll*, ou mesmo barra de navegação. Para um sistema desse tipo vc pode usar as medidas de `viewport` por exemplo (`vw, vh, vmin, vmax`). Assim vc garante que a tela vai ocupar 100% da área visível do dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para esses tipos de dispositivos mais "flexíveis", que podem variar a orientação e mudar de tamanho de tela a todo o momento é interessante usar medidas relativas. Se são muitas ou poucas as opções de medida do CSS eu não sei... o importante é saber quais usar para cada tipo de problema. Em uma interface em que o usuário vai usar muito o *zoom* do *browser* vc pode adotar medidas em `px`, já para telas onde o usuário não pode dar *zoom* seria legal medidas relativas.

Comment: "Diferentes unidades para diferentes demandas"

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente podemos definir as unidades de medidas em duas categorias:

**1. Medidas absolutas :** Mesmo com telas diferentes elas aparecerá exatamente com esse tamanho. 
cm  
mm  
in  
px
pt
pc

**2. Medidas relativas** Seu tamanho é relativo podendo variar de acordo com o tamanho da tela ou equipamento ( muito usada para layouts responsivos ) 
em  
ex
ch
rem
vw
vh
vmin
vmax

As diferentes unidades nos ajuda a definir diferentes tipos de parâmetros, por exemplo:
Caso esteja redimensionando uma imagem no CSS que temos seu tamanho e **px**, dependendo da aplicação desta imagem no layout será mais conveniente definir seu tamanho em **px**, mas caso queira definir seu tamanho em relação a um elemento o melhor será definir em **em**. 
Outro exemplo seria um texto, fica mais fácil definir na maioria das vezes em **pt**, principalmente se for algum texto com finalidade de impressão.
Então cada unidade de medida tem seu propósito de facilitar dependendo do tipo que aplicação que quer definir.

Comment: OK, você definiu as unidades de medidas. Mas por que tem tantas?

Comment: As diferentes unidades nos ajuda a definir diferentes tipos de parâmetros, por exemplo, caso esteja redimensionando uma imagem no CSS que temos seu tamanho e px dependendo da aplicação desta imagem no layout será mais conveniente definir seu tamanho em "px", mas caso queira definir seu tamanho em relação a um elemento o melhor será definir em "em". Outro exemplo seria um texto, fica mais fácil definir na maioria das vezes em pt.
Então cada unidade de medida tem seu propósito de facilitar dependendo do tipo que aplicação que quer definir.

Comment: Seria interessante complementar sua resposta.

Comment: Editado a resposta, espero ter ajudado!